# Display specific regional characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, regional-settings

I need to display `LST ISO/IEC 8859-13` codepage characters on window. Currently I'm using `ShowMessage` function for this purpose. Evrything displayed fine when windows locale is from this region, but how to deal when I have for example locale English UK? In this case I have just "?" instead of character. It should be some kind of possibility to show regional characters since MS Word displays them without correct locale. But how to do that?

Comment: Simply use Unicode. You get native support in Delphi 2009+.

Answer (score 2):

You have two viable, tractable options:

1. Upgrade to a Unicode version of Delphi that has built in support for international text, or
2. Use the TNT Unicode controls that graft that support onto pre-Unicode Delphi by using the COM `WideString` type which is encoded using Unicode.

Word has no problems doing this because it uses the native Unicode API of Windows. On the other hand Delphi 7 uses the ANSI API that exists solely to provide compatibility with Windows 95/98/ME.

Answer (score 2):

Short version:

you must also set the Font.Charset property if you want to be (more) sure that a particular component will display characters in a given charset.

Long version (sorry: i am prone to be wordy)

Using unicode (and you should switch to an unicode version of delphi, if you haven't done it yet) does not guarantee that the fonts installed on a foreign pc will contain the all the symbols you want to display. 
 Using unicode, moreover, does nothing to force the operating system to choose a font that actually supports the charset you need: even if there is an installed font able to display cyrillic characters, windows will NOT choose that font just because you are asking him to render a string containing cyrillic unicode code points: it will still be using the default system fonts.

So: there always is the possibility that you will need to ask your customers to install a font supporting the charset your application needs. if this can be a serious issue, you should consider the idea of distributing the required fonts along with your binaries (be careful with font copirights).
 In second place: if there are components in your application you are SURE that they will always show russian text, well, in such components you MUST assign Font.Charset = RUSSIAN_CHARSET. This is the way of telling windows "I really need to display cyrillic chars in this component, so choose an appropriate font, regardeless of which side of the planet you are running"

It is a common misconception that che charset property is useless with unicode programs. it is quite the opposite.

Another common error is to assume that the "XYZ" font is identical on all windows installations in the world so, if I can see cyrillic chars with Thamoa on my pc, then I am safe using Thamoa for displaying cyrillic in the rest of the world. it is quite the opposite: a different unicode subset gets installed depending on the computer locale.

and... Since AFAIK ShowMessage() uses the system default font, you can't use this procedure for displaying messages containing "strange" characters: you need to write your own ShowMessage dialog box.

EDIT: here is an example demonstrating what I am saying

just drop  a TPaintBox component on a form, name it "pbox", and write this OnPaint event handler:
 (remember to save the source in utf-8 format, otherwise the russian symbols will be mangled)

```
procedure TForm1.pboxPaint(Sender: TObject);
begin
   pbox.canvas.Font.Name := 'Fixedsys';
   pbox.Canvas.TextOut(0,0,'Это русский'); 

   pbox.canvas.Font.Name := 'Fixedsys';
   pbox.canvas.Font.Charset := RUSSIAN_CHARSET;
   pbox.Canvas.TextOut(0,20,'Это русский'); 
end;
```

On an italian pc (and I guess on any west-european or american pc) the fixedsys font does not normally contain the russian characters symbols: the first TextOut will insist in using the FixedSys font and will write garbage. On my pc i get a sequence of black square boxes, for example.

The second textout is made after having set charset=RUSSIAN_CHARSET, so windows will know that we need the russian symbols and so chooses another font. The second TextOut is not using the FixedSys font I wanted to use, but at least it is readable!

On a russian installation of windows, both TextOut calls will correctly render the russian text using the FixedSys font, since russian installations of windows have a russian version of the fixedsys font. and Windows knows it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install more than one locale on a Windows system. If you are using the matching locale then it is the default locale and you can use a dialog with a text field which uses the correct locale / character set. On your development system, where English UK is installed, add the missing language(s).

Unicode is nicer, but not required to display characters from non-default character sets (computers were able to handle many character sets before Uincode was invented). Even MS Wordpad was able to display characters from different codepages, including multi-byte character sets (Korean, Japanese, Chinese) long before Unicode existed.

ShowMessage can not be used because it sticks to the default locale. But can easily be replaced with a custom dialog-style form.

Comment: Under Control Panel->Region->Administrative->Change system locale I can select only one locale. Where I can add others? I'm using Windows 8

Comment: ShowMessage (in D7) use the system message font. How can an application use the character set it wants?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz right, but I wrote in my answer, that a dialog with a text field is needed (instead of the ShowMessage which sticks to the default locale)

Comment: @user1501700 I updated the answer, you can add languages in the Control Panel.

Comment: ASCII table has 256 chars and extended part of it is used for international characters. As far I understand extended part in different languages represent different chars (for example char 208 looks different in  http://www.likit.lt/nostyle/1257.htm and http://www.asciitable.com/) . How system will know which language it needs to select to represent character

Comment: @user1501700 ASCII uses 7 bit, so it can not encode 256 different characters